# Difference between InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD and TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD

Tags: android

How do you know whether to use 
`android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD` or `android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`?

The documentation of `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD`:

> Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: entering password inside of a web form. This was added in HONEYCOMB. An IME must target this API version or later to see this input type; if it doesn't, a request for this type will be seen as TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD when passed through EditorInfo.makeCompatible(int).

The documentation of `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`:

> Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: entering a password.

In which case is a form considered a "web form"?
Is there any difference in behavior between the two? (visually and/or logically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In which case is a form considered a "web form"?

If EditText( html input field) is inside browser page( any web form which takes input from user).

We need to use InputType `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD` in case of web-from.

if EditText is object of [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)  in native application then need to use `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`

> Is there any difference in behaviour between the two? (visually and/or
>   logically)

YES,

See [com.android.inputmethod.latin.InputAttributes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/inputmethod/latin/InputAttributes.java) here:

`TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT` flag is used :

```
 // If it's a browser edit field and auto correct is not ON explicitly, then
 // disable auto correction, but keep suggestions on.
 // If NO_SUGGESTIONS is set, don't do prediction.
 // If it's not multiline and the autoCorrect flag is not set, then don't correct
```

But in case of `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` InputType above comments are not TRUE.